# $n$ balls in $n$ boxes

Tags: probability

```
Each of n balls is independently placed into one of n boxes, with all boxes equally likely.
What is the probability that exactly one box is empty?
```

What is wrong with my reasoning below?

Every time I make a decision of which box I put the ball in, I have to choose from $n$ boxes.

$\binom{n}{n-1}$ - here I choose from $n-1$ boxes. The box left out is the one that will be empty. I do this at every decision I make, so if I have three balls, I have to make this decision three times, i.e. at each branch, I have to ensure to pick all but one box.
So if I had $n = 3$, I would have $\binom{n}{n-1} \binom{n}{n-1} \binom{n}{n-1}$

Hence my answer was

$$\frac{\binom{n}{n-1}^n}{n^n}$$

But that's clearly wrong. Not sure where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: The empty one is the same for all divisions and you aren’t ensuring that there’s exactly 1 empty (and not like all balls going into the same bin).

Comment: In how many ways can you choose the box where there are 2 balls? In how many ways can those 2 balls be chosen? How many boxes are available where the two balls can fall? How many boxes are available where the rest of the balls can fall? remember that one must be empty

Comment: Is the number of balls the same as the number of boxes, as implied in the main body? The difference in case in the title is a bit distracting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first we choose the number of empty bin: $n$ ways. Then we need to choose the bin with exactly 2 balls: $(n-1)$ ways. Then we need to choose serial numbers of balls that will fall into the chosen bin: $\binom{n}{2}$ ways. For left $n-2$ balls any permutation is suitable, so the result formula for variants is:
$$n(n-1)\binom{n}{2}(n-2)! = n!\binom{n}{2}$$
Example, $n=3$. Suitable variants are (for each ball the number of bin it reached is written):

- only first bin is empty, so $(223)$, $(232)$, $(322)$, $(332)$, $(323)$, $(233)$
- only second bin is empty, so $(113)$, $(131)$, $(311)$, $(331)$, $(313)$, $(133)$
- only third bin is empty, so $(112)$, $(121)$, $(211)$, $(221)$, $(212)$, $(122)$

So the answer is:
$$p = \frac{n!}{n^n}\binom{n}{2}$$

I checked it with `Python3`. The formula is correct!

Comment: Would you be able to comment on how you approach such a problem. I seem to always be holding the wrong end of the stick, and can never find the “trick” with these (in this case that we have to fill all boxes with 1 ball and for one box take it out)

Comment: @IGottaLearnMath In such problems it is useful to create a model of elementary outcome: here we have a sequence of numbers which mean the serial number of bin the ball reached. So (213) means that first ball goes to bin #2, then second goes to bin #1 and the last one goes to bin #3. And then you need to solve a combinatorial problem, where the trick I used is quite standard. So you can try to find some pure combinatorial problems to train on.

Comment: Couple things: where does the $n^n$ appear from in the numerator in your final result? 
Also, when you define $(n-1)$ as choosing the bin with exactly two balls, this could also be defined as “choose every ball except one”, since n is also the number of balls. 
Similarly, when you say “we need to choose two balls that will fall into the chosen bin” and use $\binom{n}{2}$ , this could also be interpreted as choose 2 bins from the total number of bins (since there are also n bins). So how would this make sense in this case? Thanks

Comment: @IGottaLearnMath $n^n$ is the total number of possible elementary outcomes. For each of $n$ balls we have $n$ possible bins, so $n\times n\times \dots\times n$ possible ways. Yes, we can have the alternative logic: for each of $n!$ permutations we can have $\binom{n}{2}$ ways to choose the number of bin to contain 2 balls: $(123)\to(113), (121), (122)$